# Is locking some object in one method is also makes it locked in other method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

When some thread locks `myList` in `SomeMethodA` and while executing the block inside `lock`, does other thread can execute `myList.Add(1)` in `SomeMethodB` or it will wait because 'myList' is locked in `SomeMethodA`?

```
class A
{
    private List<int> myList;

    public void SomeMethodA()
    {
       lock(myList)
       {
          //...
       }
    }

    public void SomeMethodB()
    {
       myList.Add(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit** Explicit answer: *No*, you need to lock the list explicitely in the `SomeMethodB`. The compiler will not automatically add locks for you

- why would you ever have to explicitely lock otherwise?
- things would be horribly slow. It would be far better to just forbid multi threading than to always lock each object access<sup>1</sup>

The recommended idiom is this:

```
class A
{
    private List<int> myList;
    private readonly object _lockObject = new Object();

    public void SomeMethodA()
    {
       lock(_lockObject)
       {
          //...
       }
    }

    public void SomeMethodB()
    {
       lock(_lockObject)
       {
           myList.Add(1);
       }
    }
}
```

Beware of exposing finegrained locking like that (you'd typically want to do coarsegrained locking as long as no blocking operations can occur under the lock).

**Note** Locks in C# are reentrant, though, so calling  `SomeMethodB` from within the lock in `SomeMethodA` will not deadlock

**Update** Rationale behind using a private lock `object` instance:

> In general, avoid locking on a public type, or instances beyond your code's control. The common constructs lock (this), lock (typeof (MyType)), and lock ("myLock") violate this guideline:
>
> - `lock (this)` is a problem if the instance can be accessed publicly.
> - `lock (typeof (MyType))` is a problem if `MyType` is publicly accessible.
> - `lock("myLock")` is a problem because any other code in the process using the same string, will share the same lock.
>
> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

---

<sup>1</sup> (aside from other issues with that approach, such as null values, reference updates, deadlocks etc.)

Comment: 1 - generally, am I right? 2 - why I cannot lock `myList` and need to lock `_lockObject`?

Comment: @theateist Of course. Locks in C# are reentrant, though, so calling  SomeMethodB from within the lock in SomeMethodA will not deadlock

Comment: @Servy Ok :) Added explicit answer at the top

Answer (score 2):

Locking an object locks it globally in your application. You can even observe the lock in other classes (if you locked a public object).

However, in your example code, `myList.Add(1)` would **not** wait for the lock because you haven't wrapped it in a `lock` block.

When we say "locking an object" or "acquiring an object lock", it is kind of a misnomer because `lock` statement actually doesn't have **anything to do** with preventing access to the object. Instead, it prevents multiple threads from entering the locked *block of code* by using that object as the "key" -- and only one thread at a time can have the key. So when you "lock" an object, all threads are still free to use the object, but only one thread at a time can use that object to enter a `lock` block.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer is No**. Once one thread has acquired the lock on some object (In your case `myList`) no other thread can access the lock of this object, Thread1 will block all other threads until Thread1 release the lock of `myList` but the condition is that if other threads are also trying for lock.

In you example if Thread1 is executing `SomeMethodA()` (which has the lock of `myList`) and Thread2 is executing `SomeMethodB()` (where it is not requesting for lock), **there will not be any problem and they will not block each other**.

Consider below example for more clarification.

```
class A
{
    private List<int> myList;

    public void SomeMethodA()
    {
       lock (myList)
       {
           //...
       }
    }

    public void SomeMethodB()
    {
        myList.Add(1);
    }

    public void SomeMethodC()
    {
        lock (myList)
        {
            myList.Add(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Thread1 is trying to access `SomeMethodA()`

Thread2 is trying to access `SomeMethodB()`

Thread3 is trying to access `SomeMethodC()`

Thread1 and Thread2 will execute without blocking each other but Thread3 will be blocked on `myList` lock as this is already acquired by Thread1.

Comment: @Servy : No , because one thread will be waiting for lock other thread is not requesting the lock so they can run fine.

Comment: Exactly, and that's a problem if the contents of the code blocks aren't thread safe, and it's important that only one of the code blocks is in the process of being executed at once.  That's why we have the `lock` statement to begin with.  If your statement was accurate then you could remove every instance of locking and programs would work just fine.

Comment: Your example has two different `SomeMethodB` methods.

Comment: @Servy : For you previous comment : The code will not be Thread safe but threads will not block each other.

Comment: Modifying a list is not a threadsafe operation, adding items to a list in two different threads is quite likely to cause problems, and yet you say "**there will not be any problems**".  You don't know that.  There *might* not be problems (we don't even know the code in the `lock` block), but you most certainly cannot guarantee that there won't be any problems.

Comment: **"there will not be any problems"** means problem with blocking.If you have perform operation in correct way you will have to take the benefit of locks unless the state of object may be corrupted by multiple threads.

Comment: But blocking isn't a problem, in fact, it's most likely *desirable* in this context.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put a lock inside `SomeMethodB`, all threads can access it even though you have a thread executing within `SomeMethodA`'s lock. In order to prevent threads from running `SomeMethodB` you need to implement your method like sehe did.

Comment: ok, but even if threads can access `SomeMethodB` can they execute `myList.Add(1)` or will wait(I mean in the way the code written in my post and not sehe, meaning without `lock` int `SomeMethodB`)?

Comment: Yes they will be able to access the Add method. The only thing `lock(_lockObject)` does is blocking all others `lock(_lockObject)` or `Monitor.Enter(_lockObject)`. see http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking